# BlobContainerClient throws "Error: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format"

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I am trying to implement a code to read and write blob file using Azure Storage Blobs. I am referencing this article:

https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2021/06/29/read-and-write-blob-file-from-microsoft-azure-storage-with-net-core/

I am using `.Net 6.0` and when the code executes `_client.CreateIfNotExists` throws an error saying `The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format`. I searched for the solution, but didn't see any. I see the old articles with old libraries which doesn't work for me. I am using the latest version of `Azure.Storage.Blobs`, that is `12.13.1`.

```
private BlobContainerClient _client;
_client = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);
// Only create the container if it does not exist
_client.CreateIfNotExists(PublicAccessType.BlobContainer);
```

Appreciate if someone can help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I’m wondering if public access is disabled for the storage account in which you are trying to create the container.

Comment: `Allow Blob public access` is enabled, I cross checked it again.

Comment: What kind of storage account is it?

Comment: Account kind: StorageV2 (general purpose v2)

Answer (score 1):

I tried in my environment with same code and got below results:

**Code:**

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Azurestorage
{
    class program
    {
        public class BlobRepository
        {
            private BlobContainerClient _client;
            public BlobRepository(string connectionString, string containerName)
            {
                _client = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);
                // Only create the container if it does not exist
                _client.CreateIfNotExists(PublicAccessType.BlobContainer);
            }

            public async Task Upload(string localFilePath, string pathAndFileName, string contentType)
            {
                BlobClient blobClient = _client.GetBlobClient(pathAndFileName);

                using FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath);
                await blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream, new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = contentType });
                uploadFileStream.Close();
            }
            public async Task<string> Download(string pathAndFileName)
            {
                BlobClient blobClient = _client.GetBlobClient(pathAndFileName);
                if (await blobClient.ExistsAsync())
                {
                    BlobDownloadInfo download = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();
                    byte[] result = new byte[download.ContentLength];
                    await download.Content.ReadAsync(result, 0, (int)download.ContentLength);

                    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
                }
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
        static async Task Main()
        {
                BlobRepository rep = new BlobRepository("<connection string>", "test");
                await rep.Upload("C:\\Users\\v-vsettu\\Documents\\storage\\student1.json", "blobtest/student1.json", "application/json");
                string jsonFile = await rep.Download("blobtest/student1.json");
                
        }
    }
}
```

**Console:**
[image]

[image]

**Output:**
The above code runned successfully and reflected in portal:

[image]

[image]

> `_client.CreateIfNotExists` throws an error saying `The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format`

The above error occurs :

- Ensure you have given access to the **`Allowed permissions`** of Shared Access Signature like below:

[image]

- Make sure you have provided valid blob name and check whether you are using supported version of the blob Service.